# codeigniter find by library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a codeigniter plugin that allows me to quickly create find by functions without writing code on every field in a db table?

I find myself writing a lot of functions for tables such as findbyid findbyfirstname findbyemail and so on, any libraries already written to speedup my dev time? i tried googling but i havent come across any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you have to write multiple methods in your model to find rows in a table by a specific field, you could just pass an associative array containing the fields and values you want to search to a generic function - something like:

```
function search_mytable($search=array()) {

    $this->db->select('mytable.*');
    $this->db->from('mytable');
    if(!empty($search) 
        $this->db->where($search);
}
```

There's more information about what you can pass the CI active record where method here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 1):

If it's just simple data retrieval, you can just do something like this:

```
function find($column, $value)
{    
    $this->db->where($column, $value);
    //etc
}
```

for simple queries. As BrynJ suggests, the Active Record class is rather flexible when it comes to taking parameters.